# setTimeout in javascript within function

Tags: javascript, function, settimeout

I have two functions like below,

```
func1 = function(){
    console.log("func1 is called"); 
}

func2 = function(){
    console.log("func2 is called");
    setTimeout(func1(),10000) 
}
```

When I make a call like `func2()`. I get the output but not the expected one.As you can see I have used a `setTimeout()` in `func2` and I expect some delay as specified before `func1` gets executed.

But no delay is observed both the lines gets printed to console at the same time. What am I doing wrong here or am I missing anything? Please help..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When referencing a function, you need to leave off the brackets.

```
setTimeout(func1,10000);
```

Answer (score 3):

Remove the parentheses after *func1* in your call to setTimeout.

The *setTimeout* function expects a function *reference*.

Your code passes **the result of invoking func1** to *setTimeout()* after printing an alert.

When parentheses follow the name of a function, they cause the function to be invoked.

```
func1 = function () {
    alert('func1 is called');
}

func2 = function(){
    console.log("func2 is called");
    // Invoke func1 and pass the return value (which is undefined) to setTimeout.  
    // An alert will be displayed immediately when func1 is invoked.
    setTimeout(func1(),10000) 
}

func2 = function(){
    console.log("func2 is called");
    // Pass a reference to func1 to setTimeout to be invoked later.
    setTimeout(func1,10000) 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also specify an anonymous function :

```
setTimeout(function(){func1();},10000);
```

Comment: This is not needed, leaving the parentheses does the trick aswell. And is more readable then a anonymous function.

Comment: Yes, you are both right, but it is also a valid solution.

Comment: But still a redundant one in this case; there's no gain unless you want to pass arguments to the function.

Comment: @AndyE : Offer several different solutions to the asker seems to be a good thing for me.

Comment: @sdespont: I don't mean to offend, and in certain scenarios I may agree with you, but your answer promotes a somewhat poor practice of adding unnecessary bulk and inefficiencies to code.